# flowtype - How to handle mixins

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have an interface/type defined and I don't want to redefine it everywhere I want to use the mixin. Think facebook's `mixins: []` property

Example usecase:

```
const mixin = root => Object.assign(root, {bar: () => 'baz'));

class Foo { 
    constructor () { mixin(this); } 
    test () { console.log(this.bar()) } // <-- this gives an error
}
```

From what I could find online, this is what i've tried:

```
interface MyMyxin {
    bar () : string;
}

function mixin <T:Object> (root: T) : T & MyMyxin {
    return Object.assign(root, {bar: () => 'baz'});
}

class Foo {
    constructor () {
        mixin(this);
    }

    test () {
        console.log(this.bar());  //  <-- no luck
    }
}

mixin(Foo.prototype) // <--- this also does not work
```

But I can't get flow to understand that the `mixin` method adds an extra property to the object

Comment: Have you figured this one?

Comment: nope. gave up on it and manually pasted the interface everywhere i used it together with an angry TODO